# How do I check if a users input is a valid IP address or not?

Tags: php, validation, ip

I want to check if an entered input is a valid IP address or not. I would like a specific function that will help me validate a users input.

Comment: Please, don't type in all capital letters, that is considered rude in the Stake Overflow culture.  Also, the word you are looking for is "guys," not "gays."

Comment: @wallyk I'm pretty sure as well this has been asked before, but at least link to the duplicate question. The sidebar doesn't show anything appropriate, so apparently it's not that easy to find. @SANJAY Please *do* search though before asking. :)

Comment: @deceze:  I didn't look for a previous answer, but I know I've seen it asked and answered several times over the last few years.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)
```

http://www.php.net/filter_var

Example:-

```
if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
  echo 'Valid IP';
} else {
  echo 'Not Valid IP';
}
```

Comment: I usually also check to make sure it's not a private or reserved IP:  

`filter_var($agree_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE)`

Comment: is there a similar way to check that the users subnet mask input is valid?

Comment: NOTE!
It validates "::1" :(

Comment: @DavidConstantine Cause that's a valid IPv6 address.

Answer (score 13):

```
// Usually you'd get the value from $_POST or $_GET
$ip = "10.3.1.5";
if(!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
   echo "Not a valid IP address!";
}
```

You can modify this by filtering for IPv4 and IPv6 IP addresses and exclude private and reserved IPs.

http://www.php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 2):

By using `preg_match();`

```
function checkIPAddress($ipAddress) 
{
    return preg_match('/^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)(?:[.](?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){3}$/', $ipAddress);
}
```

Comment: Its detect only ipv4 ip. Not ipv6. See both IPs. `is2a02:a03f:e8ea:c00:5cbc:fd44:5a92:8399` and `38.290.20.11`