# How to match Ip address with comma separated Ips php

Tags: php, preg-match

How to match valid ip with `(,)` separated string.

I have one text box and user can input ip with comma `(,)` separated.

for that i m checking that the string contain valid ip string.

String should be

```
192.168.1.1
195.138.124.1,1.154.127.1
```

Comment: Combine explode with this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211148/how-do-i-check-if-a-users-input-is-a-valid-ip-address-or-not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested, you will obtain stronger results using build-in filters:

```
function validateIPs ($input) {
    foreach(explode(',', $input) as $ip)
        if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i m sharing with you guys. have spent almost 2 to 3 hours for this so i would like to share this with you.so you may not have to spent hours for this.

this is the regular expression for match the IP with comma separate string.

```
/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})*$/
```

[Link for check online regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/jX9vO4/1)

Comment: Well that's what you call a waste of time, first hit on google all kinds of regexes for ip adresses. Maybe not specific for comma seperated but why not use an `explode();` for that.

Comment: You'd probably be better using the inbuilt `filter_var` function, with `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`. Your regexp will match incorrect addresses - you're just checking the number of digits, so `350.350.350.350` will pass.

Comment: You can make that a bit shorter by using groups: `^(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:,(?1))*$` where `(?1)` is a reference to first parenthesized subpattern, which is the pattern for one ip address. `(?:` opens a non capturing group.